# Opendaylight: Deploy changes to Netconf source code in Integration/Distribution Code

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-karaf, opendaylight

TL;DR -> How to integrate a local Opendaylight Karaf App in the Opendaylight integration/distribution project, for local use? I am not looking to publish my code to upstream to official opendaylight repositories.

I am trying to understand how to make changes to source code of certain features in Opendaylight to fulfill my custom use-cases.

For this, I downloaded the Netconf Source code from "https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/netconf" and the distribution source code from "https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/integration/distribution".
I made certain modifications in the Netconf Code and built it using `mvn clean install -Pq -Dcheckstyle.skip`.

Now, how do I go about integrating these updates in the integration/distribution project?

FYI:

1. I am working on ODL "release/oxygen-sr2". However, I realise that newer versions are available and I am open to shifting to them.
2. Using Java 8 and Maven 3.6.0
3. I had been suggested that I could just maven build the Netconf Project code and run Apache Karaf from there. Any other feature could then be installed via the Karaf CLI. But, my use case would require modifications on multiple existing features and even creating a new feature. Therefore, this solution also doesn't work for me as I would still need to integrate everything in one central project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's pretty simple, but maybe not obvious. Build all the projects you
want locally, then build the integration/distribution project. Any artifacts it
finds in the local m2 repo will be used for the final int/dist karaf that will
get created.

in other words, for every project you want to customize, pull that repo, make
your changes, build it. Then as a last step, build the int/dist project.

Comment: This seems way simpler than I had imagined. Let me try this and get back

Comment: I think I am missing something. For quick testing, I did the following:
1. setup Netconf code and modify `/home/ubuntu/ghost/netconf/netconf/sal-netconf-connector/src/main/java/org/opendaylight/netconf/sal/connect/netconf/NetconfDevice.java:232: LOG.info("{}: Netconf connector initialized successfully by ghost", id);`
2. Build code -> mvn clean install -Pq
3. CD to distribution directory and build code there next.
4. Run Karaf and install _odl-netconf-all, odl-netconf-connector-all, odl-netconf-topology, odl-restconf-all_ features.
5. Mount a device and look for "ghost" in karaf logs.

Comment: However, I am not seeing "ghost" in the logs. I am still seeing original "Netconf connector initialized successfully" instead of "Netconf connector initialized successfully by ghost". Am I missing something?

Comment: no, that seems right. just to be safe, make sure you are building "mvn clean install" from the root of the netconf folder. once it's done, you should be able to poke around your .m2/repository/ directory to verify that netconf artifacts have recent time stamps. Then move to integration/distribution root folder and build that. The karaf created there should be using the artifacts in your local m2 repo if they are there.

also, for testing run the karaf that's created in the netconf folder just to make sure you can see your "ghost" message from that. If not, then the problem is in netconf code

Comment: I do see "ghost" message when running Karaf from netconf root folder. I will anyway retry and verify by time stamps.